# Anyone working at a company using Visual Studio Express 2010 instead of the pay version ? Does Express do enough?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-platform-installer

I am. And I am wondering if there is any good reason to use professional .. Also for hobbiest programming...

So far the only thing I have missed is being able open certain .sln files that use testing projects and more advanced things.. but that not that big of a deal.. though I do miss testing

I was first surprised that the small consulting company I am working at does not use a paid edition of VS2010 (and SVN instead of TFS and Open Office instead of MS Office)

Anyone else working at a place like this? With the new Platform installer I like how I can get a new machine running and easily check and install what I need for free so that makes it even easier.

Comment: Only you can answer "does express do enough" for you. It does not do enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's one good reason: Microsoft does [not allow 3rd party extensibility in Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielfe/archive/2007/05/31/visual-studio-express-and-testdriven-net.aspx). Plug-ins like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) add significant value to Visual Studio. I have trouble imagining doing professional work in a timely manner without them.

Comment: that is a good one. I somehow never got addicted to the ReSharper plugin yet though

Comment: It's everything - CodeRush, TestDriven.Net, GhostDoc - you name it. Add-ins/plug-ins don't work with Express.

Comment: Though we seem to be fine without them... I guess it can work for small projects after all